# SQL code to select 1 row per unique value on a field in a query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a the following table:

```
| ClientID   | Status    | Date      |
| ---------- | --------- | --------- |
| 1          | -1        | 3/1/2016  |
| 1          | 0         | 5/5/2016  |
| 2          | 0         | 3/21/2016 |
| 2          | -1        | 4/16/2016 |
| 2          | 0         | 5/1/2016  |
| 3          | 0         | 4/10/2016 |
| 3          | -1        | 5/6/2016  |
| 4          | 0         | 5/8/2016  |
```

I need my result to have one row per ClientID, and if that ClientID has a Status of -1 on any row on the table, that takes priority over a value of 0. The result should be:

```
| ClientID   | Status    | Date      |
| ---------- | --------- | --------- |
| 1          | -1        | 3/1/2016  |
| 2          | -1        | 4/16/2016 |
| 3          | -1        | 5/6/2016  |
| 4          | 0         | 5/8/2016  |
```

I have tried and tried, and looked at other similar questions here on StackExchange, but can't seem to get the result I am looking for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suppose a client has more than one row with status `-1`?  If those rows have different dates, you will have to choose which to show.  How do you resolve that?

Comment: By the way, you aren't going to name a field `Date`, are you?  `Date` is a dedicated keyword in Access, and using it for a name is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, this is just a pseudo table. Multiple -1 values dont matter, the specific date isn't important

Answer (score 1):

Trying breaking the problem into logical steps and then try optimising from there:

```
    --Prioritise on Status == -1
    select *
    from ClientTable
    where Status=-1
    UNION
--Add any remaining rows, I guess you are only interested in one, not sure which one so chose top one
    select top 1 * 
    from ClientTable
    where ClientID not in (
      select ClientID
      from ClientTable
      where Status=-1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try it this way:

```
SELECT tblStatus.ClientID, Max(tblStatus.Date) AS Date
FROM tblStatus
WHERE tblStatus.Status=
    (
    SELECT MIN(Status) 
    FROM tblStatus Status
    WHERE ClientID=tblStatus.ClientID
    )
GROUP BY tblStatus.ClientID
```

Comment: You will need to paste this in SQL View, because Access' query design interface doesn't facilitate this approach.  But you can nest a query -- that's a way to apply this solution.

Comment: This solution loses the client that has no `-1` value.  So the answer from T33C may be better.   (I think this one can be made to work, though?)

Comment: @Smandoli Please explain how it would lose the case where a client only has a 0 value. I ran a test and it returned the dataset expected.

Comment: This is great and it is working perfectly. What exactly is happening in this code? I understand the nested query is pulling the minimum value of Status for each ClientID, but what in the code is causing only 1 row per client to be selected? Is that the GROUP BY? I have never used the "HAVING" function before either so I will read up on that.

Comment: Actually the HAVING clause was unnecessary, I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JJ32 -- perhaps my test was faulty;  less likely, running it in SQL Server produced a different result.  Whatever the case, I'm sorry for the incorrect criticism.  Now, of course, the person who posted the question should ACCEPT your answer!